# API PagSeguro 401 error - Unauthorized; Erro ao iniciar sessão pagseguro

Tags: node.js, express.js, pagamento-online, fetch

[RESOLVIDO]
Fiz um servidor node simples para testar a API do PagSeguro e estou tendo problemas com o erro 401.
Em um vídeo vi que para realizar requisições para a API PagSeguro é necessário ter um certificado SSL, portanto fiz um deploy no heroku 
 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] 
Como da pra ver na imagem acima o cadeado está fechado e a URL inicia com `https://` o que significa que o endereço tem um certificado SSL, porém mesmo assim a API está dando erro.

Já tentei resolver este problema de várias formas, inclusive utilizando o cors-anywhere tanto online, quanto localmente e também não deu certo.

Fiz uma requizição utilizando o aplicativo desktop Postman e nele a requisição retornou status 200
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Na requisição do postman não configurei nenhum header, apenas selecionei a opção `x-www-form-urlencoded` e coloqueis as informações [email, token]

#### Informações:

- As credenciais [email, token] estão corretas
- O deploy não contem erros

Segue abaixo o código do servidor node:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const Headers = fetch.Headers
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('working pgs')
})

app.get('/teste', async (req, res) => {
  const r = await fetch('https://ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/sessions/', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: new Headers({"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"}),
    body: {
      email: encodeURIComponent(process.env.PGS_EMAIL),
      token: encodeURIComponent(process.env.PGS_TOKEN)
    }
  })
  const t = await r.text()
  console.log(r)
  res.send(`teste ${JSON.stringify(r)}`)
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3333)
```

Espero ter sintetizado minha dúvida de maneira fácil de ser entendida se por um acaso estiver faltando alguma informação por favor me avise que eu coloco aqui.

#### Link do heroku: `https://node-deploy-pgs.herokuapp.com/teste`

Comment: Não é preciso indicar no texto da pergunta que o problema foi resolvido. Basta aceitar uma resposta que já saberemos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse body que você colocou está totalmente errado:

```
body: {
  email: encodeURIComponent(process.env.PGS_EMAIL),
  token: encodeURIComponent(process.env.PGS_TOKEN)
}
```

Não é assim que o `fetch()` trabalha, se é `x-www-form-urlencoded` use o [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams), simplesmente assim (e NÃO precisa do `encodeURIComponent`, o `URLSearchParams` já resolve isso):

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const { URLSearchParams } = require('url');

...

const r = await fetch('https://ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/sessions/', {
    method: 'post',
    body: new URLSearchParams({
      email: process.env.PGS_EMAIL,
      token: process.env.PGS_TOKEN
    })
})
```

Como a própria documentação do módulo que você instalou sugere:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#post-with-form-parameters

Você também pode usar o módulo (instalado a parte https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) form-data, conforme o exemplo:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const FormData = require('form-data');

...

const form = new FormData();

form.append('email', process.env.PGS_EMAIL);
form.append('token', process.env.PGS_TOKEN);

const r = await fetch('https://ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/sessions/', {
    method: 'post',
    body: form
})
```

Não precisa configurar o header, os bodys `x-www-form-urlencoded` e `form-data` são "naturais", portanto internamente os headers são "resolvidos".

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado, ainda estou aprendendo a fazer http requests